# Python objects in dealloc in Cython

Tags: cython

In the documentation it is written that "Any C data that you explicitly allocated (e.g., via [malloc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation)) in your _*cinit*_() method should be freed in your _*dealloc*_() method."

This is not my case. I have following extension class:

```
cdef class SomeClass:
    cdef dict data
    cdef void * u_data

    def __init__(self, data_len):
        self.data = {'columns': []}
        if data_len > 0:
            self.data.update({'data': deque(maxlen=data_len)})
        else:
            self.data.update({'data': []})
        self.u_data = <void *>self.data

    @property
    def data(self):
        return self.data

    @data.setter
    def data(self, new_val: dict):
        self.data = new_val
```

Some C function has an access to this class and it appends some data to SomeClass().data dict. What should I write in `__dealloc__`, when I want to delete the instance of the SomeClass()?

Maybe something like:

```
def __dealloc__(self):
    self.data = None
    free(self.u_data)
```

Or isn't there any need to dealloc anything at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No you don't need to and no you shouldn't. From [the documentation](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/special_methods.html#finalization-method-dealloc)

> You need to be careful what you do in a `__dealloc__()` method. By the time your `__dealloc__()` method is called, the object may already have been partially destroyed and may not be in a valid state as far as Python is concerned, so you should avoid invoking any Python operations which might touch the object. In particular, don’t call any other methods of the object or do anything which might cause the object to be resurrected. It’s best if you stick to just deallocating C data.
>
> You don’t need to worry about deallocating Python attributes of your object, because that will be done for you by Cython after your `__dealloc__()` method returns.

---

You can confirm this by inspecting the C code (you need to look at the full code, not just the annotated HTML). There's an autogenerated function `__pyx_tp_dealloc_9someclass_SomeClass` (name may vary slightly depending on what you called your module) does a range of things including:

```
__pyx_pw_9someclass_9SomeClass_3__dealloc__(o);
/* some other code */
Py_CLEAR(p->data);
```

where the function `__pyx_pw_9someclass_9SomeClass_3__dealloc__` is (a wrapper for) your user-defined `__dealloc__`. `Py_CLEAR` will ensure that `data` is appropriately reference-counted then set to `NULL`.

It's a little hard to follow because it all goes through several layers of wrappers, but you can confirm that it does what the documentation says.

Comment: Hi @davidW, I have a similar question, since __dealloc__ is not required, how about __cinit__ in this case?

Comment: @jim I've decided not to participate in Stack Overflow for the moment since they announced a free-for-all on AI generated answers. Sorry

Comment: that is really unfortunate but I respect your stance on the matter.